# Thread safe version of List<T> - Implementation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

After going through lots of posts on Stack Overflow, I think I am able to come up with a thread safe version of List, which is certainly not up to the level of Concurrent collections, since it use a ReaderWriterLockSlim, but in my understanding, it works as expected and has a better performance compared to the simple lock version. Anything that you may think can be improved in the current implementation. It still does not implement all functions of List, since I have just taken care of IList

Disclaimer - I have got idea from Stack Overflow, so it certainly contains bit and pieces from various posts

Modifications - Code is modified to take care of certain scenarios, which were posted in last communication like:

```
if(list.count > 0)
  return list[0]
```

There's no reason for mark this on hold as off topic

Thread Safe implementation

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;


/// <summary>
/// Thread safe version of the List using 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class ThreadSafeListWithRWLock<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> internalList;

    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim rwLockList;

    public ThreadSafeListWithRWLock()
    {
        internalList = new List<T>();

        rwLockList = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    }

    // Other Elements of IList implementation

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Clone().GetEnumerator();
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Clone().GetEnumerator();
    }

    public List<T> Clone()
    {
        List<T> clonedList = new List<T>();

        rwLockList.EnterReadLock();

        internalList.ForEach(element => { clonedList.Add(element); });

        rwLockList.ExitReadLock();

        return (clonedList);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        rwLockList.EnterWriteLock();

        internalList.Add(item);

        rwLockList.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        bool isRemoved;

        rwLockList.EnterWriteLock();

        isRemoved = internalList.Remove(item);

        rwLockList.ExitWriteLock();

        return (isRemoved);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        rwLockList.EnterWriteLock();

        internalList.Clear();

        rwLockList.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        bool containsItem;

        rwLockList.EnterReadLock();

        containsItem = internalList.Contains(item);

        rwLockList.ExitReadLock();

        return (containsItem);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        rwLockList.EnterReadLock();

        internalList.CopyTo(array,arrayIndex);

        rwLockList.ExitReadLock();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int count;

            rwLockList.EnterReadLock();

            count = internalList.Count;

            rwLockList.ExitReadLock();

            return (count);
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        int itemIndex;

        rwLockList.EnterReadLock();

        itemIndex = internalList.IndexOf(item);

        rwLockList.ExitReadLock();

        return (itemIndex);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
      rwLockList.EnterWriteLock();

      if (index <= internalList.Count - 1)
        internalList.Insert(index,item);

      rwLockList.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
       rwLockList.EnterWriteLock();

       if (index <= internalList.Count - 1)
        internalList.RemoveAt(index);

       rwLockList.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T this[int index] 
    {
        get
        {
            T returnItem = default(T);

           rwLockList.EnterReadLock();

           if (index <= internalList.Count - 1)
               returnItem = internalList[index];              

           rwLockList.ExitReadLock();

            return (returnItem);
        }
        set
        {
            rwLockList.EnterWriteLock();

            if (index <= internalList.Count - 1)
                internalList[index] = value;

            rwLockList.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use .Net Concurrent Collections?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about CodeReview

Comment: The main problem is not making each method thread safe, that's quite easy. It's making entire operations which contains multiple method calls behave in a consistent way.

Comment: @trailmax closest is the ConcurrentBag, which is not a list in real sense, since it doesn't provide me a ordered indexed approach to the data.

Comment: @DavidG, yes its a sort of code review request.

Comment: @Dirk Do you mean same as answer and comment provided below, or a different scenario, please elaborate

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The answer below is one scenario, there are countless others.

Comment: I am trying to figure out the potential issues with the code, why is it not worth the discussion. It seems to be a random decision to mark query on hold. In fact I have figured out this piece of code is faster than Concurrent classes, Immutable collections, if I share performance test details, that would also be off topic to some. Completely surprised at this on hold / off topic marking, looks like big brother is marking things on some random understanding

Answer (score 8):

This kind of implementation is a bit leaky, because even though every atomic operation (e.g. every method call) is thread safe, the overall is error prone.

To illustrate, consider this kind of code:

```
if(!myThreadSafeList.Contains(item))
       myThreadSafeList.Add(item);
```

The two operations ARE threadsafe, but the overall is not.

You could use .Net conccurent collections, as trailmax suggested in comments.

Another alternative is [to use Microsoft immutable collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx), available on Nuget.

These are thread safe, and moreover, lock free !

Ps: Learn a bit about  [compare-and-swap loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) if you intend to use immutable collections, though... implemented in C# using [Interlocked.CompareExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Indeed, and (to provide another example) code like `if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];` is still buggy and could throw an exception.

Comment: Completely agree, but I will tell you a scenario, where even concurrent collections and Immutable list fails. I have an outlook client on my system, same mail is configured on my phone too, so many times I delete the mail on phone but it is in my outlook interface of the system and on clicking on it it gives "Unknown Error", due to known reason. Similar is the case with my application, is there any collection that which can work on this scenario, in fact this scenario requires real time check and update of the interface, in current case I just need to wrap exception due above mentioned case

Comment: @MrinalKamboj That's not really a counter example, it's about synchronized access to your mail account and has nothing to do with concurrent collections.

Comment: @Dirk please explain the synchronized access across devices (Windows system, Android phone), how would you resolve above mentioned scenario. Either it has to poll and update or create a notification system, but both of them are costly ways, I have not seen MS Outlook doing it, not Android does it for Vice Versa

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Concurrent collections or making collection access thread safe refers to concurrent access **within a single process**. For updating data in another process or even on another device you either need a push or a pull approach, neither of which is the topic of the question or this answer.

Comment: @Dirk I think I was very clear about the usage scenario, you bought in the point related to synchronized access, which is a different ball game in my understanding, and our collections will not by default take care of these usage scenarios

Comment: + 1 for mentioning `Microsoft immutable collection`

Comment: @ebb be careful while using immutable collections, they are apparently performance nightmare. check this out:
http://ayende.com/blog/164739/immutable-collections-performance

Comment: @Matthew Watson,@Olivier, as suggested above Immutable collections are not good for performance. If I take care of certain explicit scenarios, then this custom code is faster than ConcurrentBag (even in.Net 4.5). As the number of read and writes increase it keeps becoming faster. Contrary to earlier impression, concurrent APIs may not be as performance oriented as expected

Comment: @Matthew Watson, for the code you have mentioned:
    if (list.Count > 0) return list[0];
Indexer can be modified to return null, which is an expected result in Multi-threaded scenario, I am not sure if anything better would be possible and acceptable